# Code doesn't switch while loops under conditional

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I have a final project in which we had to create a Choose Your Own Adventure game, in which I decided to go all out and create a mini version of Dark Souls, but I may have bitten off more than I can chew. Within the fight sequence, I have a random int that rolls a number 1-10, if the number is 2 or 8, the fight sequencing begins, and another while loop SHOULD start, but doesn't. Any advice as to how to switch while loops on the fly?

```
import random
import time


print('''
▓█████▄  ▄▄▄       ██▀███   ██ ▄█▀     ██████  ▒█████   █    ██  ██▓      ██████    
▒██▀ ██▌▒████▄    ▓██ ▒ ██▒ ██▄█▒    ▒██    ▒ ▒██▒  ██▒ ██  ▓██▒▓██▒    ▒██    ▒    
░██   █▌▒██  ▀█▄  ▓██ ░▄█ ▒▓███▄░    ░ ▓██▄   ▒██░  ██▒▓██  ▒██░▒██░    ░ ▓██▄      
░▓█▄   ▌░██▄▄▄▄██ ▒██▀▀█▄  ▓██ █▄      ▒   ██▒▒██   ██░▓▓█  ░██░▒██░      ▒   ██▒   
░▒████▓  ▓█   ▓██▒░██▓ ▒██▒▒██▒ █▄   ▒██████▒▒░ ████▓▒░▒▒█████▓ ░██████▒▒██████▒▒   
 ▒▒▓  ▒  ▒▒   ▓▒█░░ ▒▓ ░▒▓░▒ ▒▒ ▓▒   ▒ ▒▓▒ ▒ ░░ ▒░▒░▒░ ░▒▓▒ ▒ ▒ ░ ▒░▓  ░▒ ▒▓▒ ▒ ░   
 ░ ▒  ▒   ▒   ▒▒ ░  ░▒ ░ ▒░░ ░▒ ▒░   ░ ░▒  ░ ░  ░ ▒ ▒░ ░░▒░ ░ ░ ░ ░ ▒  ░░ ░▒  ░ ░   
 ░ ░  ░   ░   ▒     ░░   ░ ░ ░░ ░    ░  ░  ░  ░ ░ ░ ▒   ░░░ ░ ░   ░ ░   ░  ░  ░     
   ░          ░  ░   ░     ░  ░            ░      ░ ░     ░         ░  ░      ░ ''')
input("                             Press Enter to continue...")




def menu():
    global game
    game = input('New game\nContinue game\nSettings\nThe game\nHelp\nExit game\nChoose here: ').lower()
    if (game == 'continue game' or game == 'new game'):
        name = input('Name your character: ')
moveCount = 0 
def move():
    move = input('What is your next move? Input MoveList for help: ')
    if (move == 'MoveList'):
        print('''
        Valid moves:
        Forward
        Look around
        Status check
        ''')
    elif (move == 'Forward'):
        global moveCount
        moveCount += 1
        if (moveCount == 5) and not(enemySpawn == 2 or enemySpawn == 8):
            estus = input('Refill your estus? Yes/No: ').lower()
            while(estus == 'yes'):
                if (estusC == 3):
                    print('Wha.. you\'re full!')
                elif (hp <= 200):
                    drink = input('Drink some estus instead? Yes/No: ').lower()
                    if (drink == 'yes'):
                        hp += 150
                elif (estus == 3 and hp > 200):
                    print('You\'re just being greedy now.')
                break
    elif (move == 'Look around'):
        print('''
        The Cemetery of Ash.
        You remember having a long and strenuous battle here.
        Somewhere at least.
        Lots of lightning and dragons.
        You see the fabled Iudex citadel ahead of you.
        What are you doing, daydreaming, Ashen One?
        Persevere.
        Move on.''')

    if (move == 'Status check'):
        print('You have {} hp and {} mana. You have {} estus flasks. Soon enough, you\'ll be able to replenish your estus.' .format(hp, mana, estusC))
    move = input('What is your next move? Input MoveList for help: ')

enemySpawn = random.randint(1,10)    
enemyHP  = random.randint(200, 450)
def spawnEnemy():
    global enemyHP
    global enemySpawn
    enemySpawn = random.randint(1,10)
    enemyHP  = random.randint(200, 450)
    if (enemySpawn == 2 or enemySpawn == 8):
        print('AN ENEMY HAS APPEARED!')
        spawn = True
    if (200 <= enemyHP <= 250):
        print('Wow, what a weakling huh?')
        damage = random.randint(25,50)
        enemyRoll()
    elif (250 < enemyHP <= 350):
        print('The average hollow.')
        damage = random.randint(50,75)
        enemyRoll()
    elif (350 < enemyHP <= 450):
        print('This one is gonna be tough!!')
        damage = random.randint(75,125)
        enemyRoll()
    print('You have {} hp left.' .format(hp))   
    

def enemyRoll():
    global hp
    if (diff == 'easy'):
        roll = random.randint(1,6)
        if (roll == 2 or roll == 4):
            print('The hollow swings...')
            time.sleep(1)
            print('and...')
            time.sleep(1)
            print('HIT!')
            hit = True
            hp = hp - damage
            print('You have {} hp left.' .format(hp))   
        else:
            print('The hollow missed..')
            hit = False
    elif (diff == 'medium'):
        roll = random.randint(1,6)
        if (roll == 2 or roll == 1 or roll == 3):
            print('The hollow swings...')
            time.sleep(1)
            print('and...')
            time.sleep(1)
            print('HIT!')
            hit = True
            hp = hp - damage
            print('You have {} hp left.' .format(hp))   
        else:
            print('The hollow missed..')
            hit = False
    elif (diff == 'hard'):
        roll = random.randint(1,6)
        if (roll == 1 or roll == 2 or roll == 3 or roll == 4):
            print('The hollow swings...')
            time.sleep(1)
            print('and...')
            time.sleep(1)
            print('HIT!')
            hit = True
            hp = hp - damage
            print('You have {} hp left.' .format(hp))   
        else:
            print('The hollow missed..')
            hit = False
        
def stats():
    print()
    print('Your Soul Level is', SL)
    print('Your vigor is', VIG)
    print('Your attunment is', ATT)
    print('Your endurance is', END)
    print('Your vitality is', VIT)
    print('Your strength is', STR)
    print('Your dexterity is', DEX)
    print('Your intelligence and faith is {} and {}, respectively.' .format(INT, FTH))
    print('Your luck is', LCK)
menu()
diff = 'medium'
if (game == 'settings'):
        print('{:>12}\n{:>12}\n{:>12}' .format('Easy', 'Medium', 'Hard'))
        print('{:>12}\n{:>12}\n{:>12}' .format('Enemies have a 1/3 chance of hitting you', 'Enemies have a 1/2 chance of hitting you', 'Enemies have a 2/3 chance of hitting you'))
        diff = input('{:>12}' .format('Choose Difficulty: ').lower())
        menu()
        if (diff != 'easy' or diff != 'medium' or diff != 'hard'):
            print('Choose again, that wasn\'t an option.')
            diff = input('{:>12}' .format('Choose Difficulty: '.lower()))
        else:
            diff == 'medium'

choice = input('''
    Knight
    Mercenary
    Warrior
    Herald
    Thief
    Assassin
    Sorcerer
    Pyromancer
    Deprived
    Choose your class... (CASE SPECIFIC!!)
    Enter selection: ''') 
if (choice == 'Knight'):
    SL = 9
    VIG = 12
    ATT = 10
    END = 11
    VIT = 15
    STR = 13
    DEX = 12
    INT = 9
    FTH = 9
    LCK = 7
    weapon = 'Longsword'
    shield = 'Knight Shield'
    stats()
elif (choice == 'Mercenary'):
    SL = 8
    VIG = 11
    ATT = 12
    END = 11
    VIT = 10
    STR = 10
    DEX = 16
    INT = 10
    FTH = 8
    LCK = 9
    weapon = 'Sellsword Twinblades'
    shield = 'Wooden Shield'
    stats()
elif (choice == 'Warrior'):
    SL = 7
    VIG = 14
    ATT = 6
    END = 12
    VIT = 11
    STR = 16
    DEX = 9
    INT = 8
    FTH = 9 
    LCK = 11
    weapon = 'Battle Axe'
    shield = 'Round Shield'
    stats()
elif (choice == 'Herald'):
    SL = 9
    VIG = 14
    ATT = 10
    END = 9
    VIT = 12
    STR = 12
    DEX = 11
    INT = 8
    FTH = 13
    LCK = 11
    weapon = 'Spear'
    shield = 'Kite Shield'
    stats()
elif (choice == 'Thief'):
    SL = 5
    VIG = 10
    ATT = 11
    END = 10
    VIT = 9
    STR = 9
    DEX = 13
    INT = 10
    FTH = 8
    LCK = 14
    weapon = 'Bandit\'s Knife'
    shield = 'Iron Round Shield'
    stats()
elif (choice == 'Assassin'):
    SL = 10
    VIG = 10
    ATT = 14
    END = 11
    VIT = 10
    STR = 10
    DEX = 14
    INT = 11
    FTH = 9
    LCK = 10
    weapon = 'Estoc'
    shield = 'Target Shield'
    stats()
elif (choice == 'Sorcerer'):
    SL = 6
    VIG = 9
    ATT = 16
    END = 9
    VIT = 7 
    STR = 7
    DEX = 12
    INT = 16
    FTH = 7
    LCK = 12
    weapon = 'Mail Breaker'
    shield = 'Leather Shield'
    stats()
elif (choice == 'Pyromancer'):
    SL = 8
    VIG = 11
    ATT = 12
    END = 10
    VIT = 8
    STR = 12
    DEX = 9
    INT = 14
    FTH = 14
    LCK = 7
    weapon = 'Hand Axe'
    shield = 'Caduceus Round Shield'
    stats()
elif (choice == 'Cleric'):
    SL = 7
    VIG = 10
    ATT = 14
    END = 9
    VIT = 7
    STR = 12
    DEX = 8
    INT = 7
    FTH = 16
    LCK = 13
    weapon = 'Mace'
    shield = 'Blue Wooden Shield'
    stats()
elif (choice == 'Deprived'):
    SL = 1
    VIG = 10
    ATT = 10
    END = 10
    VIT = 10
    STR = 10
    DEX = 10
    INT = 10
    FTH = 10
    LCK = 10
    weapon = 'Club'
    shield = 'Plank Shield'
    stats()




time.sleep(5)
print(''' 
█     █░▓█████  ██▓     ▄████▄   ▒█████   ███▄ ▄███▓▓█████ 
▓█░ █ ░█░▓█   ▀ ▓██▒    ▒██▀ ▀█  ▒██▒  ██▒▓██▒▀█▀ ██▒▓█   ▀ 
▒█░ █ ░█ ▒███   ▒██░    ▒▓█    ▄ ▒██░  ██▒▓██    ▓██░▒███   
░█░ █ ░█ ▒▓█  ▄ ▒██░    ▒▓▓▄ ▄██▒▒██   ██░▒██    ▒██ ▒▓█  ▄ 
░░██▒██▓ ░▒████▒░██████▒▒ ▓███▀ ░░ ████▓▒░▒██▒   ░██▒░▒████▒
░ ▓░▒ ▒  ░░ ▒░ ░░ ▒░▓  ░░ ░▒ ▒  ░░ ▒░▒░▒░ ░ ▒░   ░  ░░░ ▒░ ░
  ▒ ░ ░   ░ ░  ░░ ░ ▒  ░  ░  ▒     ░ ▒ ▒░ ░  ░      ░ ░ ░  ░
  ░   ░     ░     ░ ░   ░        ░ ░ ░ ▒  ░      ░      ░   
    ░       ░  ░    ░  ░░ ░          ░ ░         ░      ░  ░
                        ░                                   ''')
time.sleep(5)
print('''
▄▄▄█████▓ ▒█████     ▄▄▄█████▓ ██░ ██ ▓█████ 
▓  ██▒ ▓▒▒██▒  ██▒   ▓  ██▒ ▓▒▓██░ ██▒▓█   ▀ 
▒ ▓██░ ▒░▒██░  ██▒   ▒ ▓██░ ▒░▒██▀▀██░▒███   
░ ▓██▓ ░ ▒██   ██░   ░ ▓██▓ ░ ░▓█ ░██ ▒▓█  ▄ 
  ▒██▒ ░ ░ ████▓▒░     ▒██▒ ░ ░▓█▒░██▓░▒████▒
  ▒ ░░   ░ ▒░▒░▒░      ▒ ░░    ▒ ░░▒░▒░░ ▒░ ░
    ░      ░ ▒ ▒░        ░     ▒ ░▒░ ░ ░ ░  ░
  ░      ░ ░ ░ ▒       ░       ░  ░░ ░   ░   
             ░ ░               ░  ░  ░   ░  ░''')
time.sleep(5)
print('''
 ▄████████    ▄████████   ▄▄▄▄███▄▄▄▄      ▄████████     ███        ▄████████    ▄████████ ▄██   ▄         ▄██████▄     ▄████████         ▄████████    ▄████████    ▄█    █▄    
███    ███   ███    ███ ▄██▀▀▀███▀▀▀██▄   ███    ███ ▀█████████▄   ███    ███   ███    ███ ███   ██▄      ███    ███   ███    ███        ███    ███   ███    ███   ███    ███   
███    █▀    ███    █▀  ███   ███   ███   ███    █▀     ▀███▀▀██   ███    █▀    ███    ███ ███▄▄▄███      ███    ███   ███    █▀         ███    ███   ███    █▀    ███    ███   
███         ▄███▄▄▄     ███   ███   ███  ▄███▄▄▄         ███   ▀  ▄███▄▄▄      ▄███▄▄▄▄██▀ ▀▀▀▀▀▀███      ███    ███  ▄███▄▄▄            ███    ███   ███         ▄███▄▄▄▄███▄▄ 
███        ▀▀███▀▀▀     ███   ███   ███ ▀▀███▀▀▀         ███     ▀▀███▀▀▀     ▀▀███▀▀▀▀▀   ▄██   ███      ███    ███ ▀▀███▀▀▀          ▀███████████ ▀███████████ ▀▀███▀▀▀▀███▀  
███    █▄    ███    █▄  ███   ███   ███   ███    █▄      ███       ███    █▄  ▀███████████ ███   ███      ███    ███   ███               ███    ███          ███   ███    ███   
███    ███   ███    ███ ███   ███   ███   ███    ███     ███       ███    ███   ███    ███ ███   ███      ███    ███   ███               ███    ███    ▄█    ███   ███    ███   
████████▀    ██████████  ▀█   ███   █▀    ██████████    ▄████▀     ██████████   ███    ███  ▀█████▀        ▀██████▀    ███               ███    █▀   ▄████████▀    ███    █▀    
                                                                                ███    ███                                                                                      ''')
def gamePlay():     
    move()
    spawnEnemy()
    enemyRoll()
                  
hp = VIG * 25
mana = ATT * 10
stam = END * 5
atk = STR * 7.5
randomifier = random.randint(0,2)
pDMG = atk * randomifier
damage = enemyHP - pDMG
estusC = 3

time.sleep(2)
print('You awaken from your grave, or was it really?')
time.sleep(1.5)
print('Nevermind.')
time.sleep(1)
print('You start with a {} and a {}. You have 3 estus flasks. You use these to heal.'.format(weapon, shield))
time.sleep(1.5)
print('You have {} health.' .format(hp))
time.sleep(1)
print('Your mana count is at {}.' .format(mana))
if (mana < 100):
    time.sleep(3)
    print('Wow..')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('A real brute, huh?')
elif (100 <= mana <= 150):
    print('The average mana count.')
else:
    print('Incredible! You truly are a mastered sorcerer!')
if (stam < 40):
    print('I guess you\'re more meant for the brains, huh?')
elif (40 <= stam <= 50):
    print('The average runner. Good for you!')
elif (stam > 50):
    print('Incredible! You have unmatched stamina!')

ready = input('Are you ready!?: ').lower()


spawn = False
while(ready == 'yes' and spawn == False):
    gamePlay()

while(spawn == True):
    spawnEnemy()
    moveF = input('What is your next move? You have four moves! Type Movelist for help: ').lower()
    if (moveF == 'movelist'):
        print('Fight\nRoll\nStatus check\nUse Estus')
        moveF = input('What is your next move? You have four moves! Type Movelist for help: ').lower()
    if (moveF == 'fight'):
        enemyRoll()
```

Comment: The only interesting `while` loop in your code is the `estus == 'yes'` loop, and because of the `break`, it will only run once and then stop.  What loop are you talking about?

Comment: And as a side note, `if` and `while` statements in Python do not use an outer set of parentheses.  That's a bad habit left over from C.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm talking about the ones at the bottom. while(ready == 'yes' and spawn == False): and while(spawn == True): When the conditionals are (supposedly) hit, I would like it to stop either while loop it is in, and switch to the other. For the second while loop, I want it to stop the first, and enter the second, for the fighting sequence, and when ended, revert back to the first to continue on with progression.

Comment: Then you need to enclose both of those loops in an outer `while True:` loop.

Comment: Didn't work, still breaks once an enemy spawns.

Comment: Then you didn't do it right.  ALL of those last 11 lines need to be indented so they are inside the `while True:`.  It has to work.